# EF code first wrapper container class has no key defined

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

**Update:**
Decided to rewrite the question as it was not very clear.

If i have class A and give it a reference to a key-less class B, instead of class B turning into its own table, all its columns will be displayed on the table for Class A - this is what i want. 
But now i want B to hold a reference to class C, which has its own table and key. What i expect now, is for table A to display the properties of B alongside a column that holds the key for C. But when i add this reference, it tells me B has no key defined and so it does not work.

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual B b{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public bool Fixed { get; set; }
    public virtual C c{ get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int CId { get; set; }
}
```

Example of how the end table should look:

```
  [AId]
      ,[Fixed]
      ,[CId]
      FROM [A]
```

I have a feeling this is a very basic question but i could not find an answer anywhere. What am i missing to make this work as desired?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your end table as a view. If you take this approach B will also need Key defined and then create an entity for a view like:

```
public class ABCView
{
    public virtual int AId { get; set; }
    public bool Fixed { get; set; }
    public virtual int CId { get; set; }
}
```

You'd need to create the view like:

```
string script =
@"
CREATE VIEW dbo.ABCView
AS SELECT a.AId,b.Fixed,c.CId
FROM dbo.a a
LEFT JOIN dbo.b b ON a.b_BId = b.BId
LEFT JOIN dbo.c c ON b.c_CId = c.CId";

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
```

then load the view like:

```
var abcItem = db.Database.SqlQuery<ABCView>("Select * from    dbo.ABCView").FirstOrDefault(abc => abc.AId == 1);
```

In the above example I am using the AId of 1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am converting from an NHibernate project, which was able to do it without your suggested method, using only the original entities. Is this just a limitation of EF6? I have been unsuccessful in identifying the setup of NH that allows it to work, but i will keep looking in case the solution to that suggests how it might be done in EF6. It is a large project and i do not look forward to converting it all to your suggested method!

Comment: I hear what you are saying but the concept you are describing - the "end table" is a database view - and using ef code first I was looking at a wAy to build a view

Comment: I guess storing the data from B in its own table and getting a key reference to it will be the least destructive way of converting this project. I am just surprised this has no cleaner solution given that its a relatively common situation - in effect it means if i ever want to encapsulate some data into another class, i will only be able to do so if the new class does not reference another entity... Unless i am willing to create a new table to store for it.
I will leave this question open for a week because i would really like to know if there is another way.

Comment: I found that the Nhibernate feature that allows this to happen in my old project is returning true for the correct type in the overridden IsComponent() function in the AutomapConfiguration class.